# How can I write the code for an inverse integral transform?

Tags: code-request, integral-transforms, code-generation

How can I code any type of integral transform with its inverse integral transform in Mathematica which gives the correct results and properties? Below is the example for Elzaki transform:

```
ElzakiTransform[f_, x_, p_] := p*Integrate[f*Exp[-x/p], {x, 0, ∞}]

ElzakiTransform[x^α, x, p]
(* ConditionalExpression[p^(2 + α) Gamma[1 + α], Re[p] > 0 && Re[α] > -1] *)
```

However, the inverse is not working:

```
InverseElzakiTransform[F_, p_, x_] := 1/(2*Pi)*Integrate[p*F*Exp[p/x], {p, -∞, ∞}]
```

Some expected properties of Elzaki transform are presented in [this tutorial](https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/Mathematica/ch6/elzaki.html).

Comment: Can you focus the question to one specific example, including it's definition and the expected output?

Comment: If you are trying to implement `InverseElzakiTransform`, presumably you have already coded `ElzakiTransform`. Edit your question to include that code so that it can be used to check the inverse.

Comment: @BobHanlon question edited and give the answer